# ffmpeg error : -vf/-af/-filter and -filter_complex cannot be used together

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to run the following cmd, which should add a watermark to the video and also upscale it.

```
ffmpeg -i "in.avi" -i "\logo.png" -vf scale=854:-1  -preset 
veryfast -crf 20 -filter_complex overlay=5:5 "ou.mkv"
```

I receive the following error.

```
Filtergraph 'scale=854:-1' was specified through the 
-vf/-af/-filter option for output stream 0:0, which is fed from 
a complex filtergraph. -vf/-af/-filter and -filter_complex 
cannot be used together for the same stream.
```

Before I tried to upscale (without the -vf scale=854:-1) the cmd worked to watermark.

How can I acheive both?

What I have tried?

- Moving the -vf parameter before the input, after the input etc.

Comment: Are you trying to upscale `in.avi`, `logo.png`, or the output from the `overlay` filter? You should use one [filtergraph](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-description) for all of your filtering.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I wish to just upscale in.avi, I tried to move the -vf scale just after in.avi and also just before in the command but it did not work. Going to read about filtergraph now Thanks!

Comment: @LongNeckbeard filtergraph worked *-filter_complex "scale=854:-1,overlay=5:5"*. If you would like to post that as an answer I will happily mark as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use one [filtergraph](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-syntax-1) to do all filtering:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -i logo.png -filter_complex \
"[0:v]scale=854:-2[scaled]; \
 [scaled][1:v]overlay=5:5[out]" \
-map "[out]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy output.mkv
```

- `[0:v]` refers to the video stream(s) of the first input (`input.avi` in this example). `[1:v]` is the video from the second input (`logo.png` in this example).
- Audio is [steam copied](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) in this example instead of being re-encoded; assuming your first input has audio.
- Best practice is to manually name the filter input and outputs, such as in this example, instead of relying on defaults which may result in improper stream selections.
- `-2` in the [scale video filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) is used instead of `-1` because x264 requires the output to be divisible by 2 when outputting to 4:2:0 chroma subsampling:

> If one of the values is -n with n > 1, the scale filter will also use a value that maintains the aspect ratio of the input image, calculated from the other specified dimension. After that it will, however, make sure that the calculated dimension is divisible by n and adjust the value if necessary.